# Resolving Network Driver issues

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers

I'm writing from my phone as my laptop fails to connect to my local home network.

In my system tray, I see the network, connect, enter the password correctly. It says connect to network... Then the network menu closes, it says no networks are available, and then says "can not connect to this network"

I did plenty of trouble shooting, and eventually noticed in the device manager that while connecting, the Adapter says "No drivers are installed for this device" when the network menu closes. I suspect the driver is crashing for one reason or another, but I can't get any further diagnostic information.

The network is a Verizon FiOS network, using the older G router, and uses WEP authentication. My laptop is compatible WEP, and has no issues connection to other networks. Other devices can also connect to this network no issue.

I've already tried Clearing my DCHP, my Local Caches, Network Settings, Forgotten the network, disabled and reenabled the device, restarted the router, reset it's factory default, updated it's firmware, and have even restarted with shutdown /rg to reregister all of my services, including the various wifi services.

Comment: You do understand that WEP is extremely insecure?  You have tried to reset both your modem and router?  You will have to clarify what your “older G router” is exactly because we don’t know what router you have.  You should edit your question to provide the necessary clarification

Comment: It's not my network or security protocol. I don't control it. The router serial number is MI424- WR. It's from Actiontec

Comment: Your modem supports WPA2 by the way.  As I said you should edit your question. I was informing you of the fact WEP is extremely insecure. What you choose to do with that information is up to you.